# Inherit new 'instance' of a static field by deriving from base class

Tags: java, oop

Consider following class hierarchy:

Base <-- Derived1

Base <-- Derived2

Base has got a static field. 
I want the derived classes to inherit that static field but each class should have its own 'instance' (by instance i mean that there are multiple static fields with the same name) of that static field. So that `Derived1.staticField` is different to `Derived2.staticField`.How do I do that?

I hope you understand my question. Tell me if you want my explanation supported by some code.

```
public class Base
{
    protected static String staticField = "Base";

    protected void printIt()
    {
        System.out.println(staticField);
    }
}

public class Derived1 extends Base
{
    //Override somehow
    protected static staticField = "Derived1";
}

public class Dervied2 extends Base
{
    //Override somehow
    protected static staticField = "Derived2";
}
```

`instanceOfBase.printIt()` prints "Base"

`instanceOfDerived1.printIt()` prints "Derived1"

`instanceOfDerived2.printIt()` prints "Derived2"

Comment: If have the some problem like that guys of the question you linked. The idea of a virtual getter method is good but is there any way not to end up with a lot static variables called `staticFieldBase`, `staticFieldDerived1`, `staticFieldDerived2` ?

Answer (score 2):

Static methods/fields are bound to the type and hence have nothing to do with instances.

You could add the same static field to your subclasses but please note this is not polymorphism - this would just be hiding. This is in line with the behavior that static methods can't be overridden by sub classes.

I would suggest to try a better approach for your solution; overridden static fields don't buy you polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this because static members are not really inherited. Inheritance is going together with polymorphism that is relevant for instances only. I think that you should better explain your real problem and I believe we can advise you to choose the better design solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't inherit anything static. It belongs to the type/class, not the instance. Inheritance can be thought of as copying non-private fields/methods from the parent class to classes that extend it.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider "a static field" as a global variable which is not even a part of Class. It's impossible to make Derived1.staticField differ from Derived2.staticField, because that's the way static field was designed.